# WriteFile does not write to STDOUT when using PeekNamedPipe

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe

I'm trying to communicate between stockfish executable and my process using the [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) provided by microsoft and making few modifications to it as below.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

static int i = 0;
 
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void); 
void WriteToPipe(void); 
void ReadFromPipe(void); 
void ErrorExit(PTSTR); 
 
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 
 
   printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

// Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
 
   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
 
   if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation")); 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
 
   if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 
 
   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation")); 
 
// Create the child process. 
   
   CreateChildProcess();

// Get a handle to an input file for the parent. 
// This example assumes a plain text file and uses string output to verify data flow. 
 
// Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
// Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
// until the child process is running before writing data.

   printf( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n");
   ReadFromPipe(); 
 
   WriteToPipe(); 
   printf( "\n->Contents of written to child STDIN pipe.\n");
 
// Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 
 
   printf( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n");
   ReadFromPipe(); 

   printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

// The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
// To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 

   return 0; 
} 
 
void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{ 
   TCHAR applicationPath[]=TEXT("../../stockfish_15.exe");
   PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE; 
 
// Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 
 
   ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
 
// Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
// This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
 
   ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
   siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
   siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
 
// Create the child process. 
    
   bSuccess = CreateProcess(applicationPath, 
      NULL,     // command line 
      NULL,          // process security attributes 
      NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
      TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
      0,             // creation flags 
      NULL,          // use parent's environment 
      NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
      &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
      &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 
   
   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
   if ( ! bSuccess ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
   else 
   {
      // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example. 

      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
      
      // Close handles to the stdin and stdout pipes no longer needed by the child process.
      // If they are not explicitly closed, there is no way to recognize that the child process has ended.
      
      CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
      CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);
   }
}
 
void WriteToPipe(void) 

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead = ARRAYSIZE("uci"), dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE] = "uci";
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
 
   {  
      bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
   } 
 
// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 
 
   if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle")); 
} 
 
void ReadFromPipe(void) 

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

   for (;;) 
   { 
      DWORD bytesAvail = 0;
      DWORD Error;
      if (!PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvail, NULL))
      {
         Error = GetLastError();
         printf("\nFailed to call PeekNamedPipe: \n");
         break;
      }

      if(bytesAvail)
      {
         bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
         if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

         bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                              dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
         if (! bSuccess ) break; 
         printf("%d\n", ++i);
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   } 
} 
 
void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction) 

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{ 
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Code relating to the question is the function ReadFromPipe

```
void ReadFromPipe(void) 

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

   for (;;) 
   { 
      DWORD bytesAvail = 0;
      DWORD Error;
      if (!PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvail, NULL))
      {
         Error = GetLastError();
         printf("\nFailed to call PeekNamedPipe: \n");
         break;
      }

      if(bytesAvail)
      {
         bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
         if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

         bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                              dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
         if (! bSuccess ) break; 
         printf("%d\n", ++i);
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   } 
}
```

However when I try printing the response that I get from stockfish in **ReadFromPipe** function, it does not display any text. I narrowed down the reason to the else block of `if(bytesAvail)` in ReadFromPipe function. If I remove the else block that breaks out of the loop then it displays text on console otherwise it does not. But remove the else blocking causes an infinite loop even though  `bytesAvail` in pipe is 0.

I'm new to winapi and would appreciate any help as to why it's happening. I have tried replacing WriteFile with printf, std::cout but none worked.

Comment: What was the value of `GetLastError()` when it failed?

Comment: `GetLastError()` breakpoint was never hit

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that when your program calls PeekNamedPipe, there really are no bytes available because Stockfish hasn't written them yet?

Comment: Yes that seems very likely. However everything prints once I remove the else clause. This is one of those edge cases that is very hard to debug.

Comment: Why is `i` declared as global? Why the BUFFSIZE macro? Why that exact value? You made mods to existing code, so the obvious question whether it worked before? What change broke it? What is `TCHAR` in your setup? I'd generally avoid `TCHAR` and related APIs and use `WCHAR` and related functions directly. Does this happen with other programs than Stockfish, in particularly commonly available ones (think [mcve])?

Comment: `i` has no significance. It was added to debug printf issues. BUFFSIZE was a macro to begin with as copied from given link. Check for `PeekNamedPipe` before reading message from pipe broke it. As @user207421 points out, it is very likely that stockfish never sent any message when I `PeekNamedPipe `. But if I from don't peek for message then `ReadFile` will go in an infinite loop since the handle is never closed by stockfish.

Comment: @MonuYadav Well, when you remove the else clause, your program keeps peeking over and over until there are bytes. When you don't remove it, your program gives up as soon as there aren't any bytes straight away.

Comment: Looks like I pinged a different user. It was @user253751 who suggested the possibility of no bytes when peeking. As I mentioned earlier, removing else clause would also cause infinite loop since the pipe is not closed by stockfish and `ReadFile` keeps waiting in expectation of receiving a message.

Comment: @MonuYadav ReadFromPipe should return after it reads all the bytes from Stockfish that Stockfish is going to eventually send, not just give up when there aren't any ready immediately. Now the question is: How do you know when you've got the whole message? If you run Stockfish yourself, in the command prompt, how do you know when you've seen the whole message?

Comment: @user253751As I am communicating using [UCI protocol](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html). I simply parse the message till I get the response required. I don't require being able to print to console within that very function. I was simply confused as to why it didn't work.

Comment: @MonuYadav But you don't parse the message until you get the response required! You wait half a microsecond and then give up because the response isn't there yet! That's why it doesn't read the response!

Comment: @user253751. I get what you are saying. After working with it some more I realized the same thing that you said. "I wasn't waiting for the message at all". Maybe you can write the same as an answer for others making the same mistake. Thank you for your help. I have one more doubt though. It's regarding this line `SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)` of code. The comment says it is preventing read handle from being inherited. But when I read the documentation it seems to me that HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT should allow it to be inherited instead. Thanks again.

Comment: @MonuYadav HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT is set to 0 (false)